Gallery Overlapping Other DOM Elements - Need Help Fixing Layout
enter image description here
I'm currently working on a project where I have a gallery implemented as a slider (.slider and .slides). However, I'm facing an issue where the gallery is overlapping other elements on the page. Despite trying different approaches, the problem persists.
The HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e2882607ff.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="building--container poppins-regular">
      <div class="slider">
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B1.jpg')"
          title="Cipher"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Project Cipher</p>
            <p class="project-description">
              Description: 2024 ***
            </p>
            <p class="client">Client: MR. Drew.</p>
            <p class="project-description">
              Role: Lead Architectural designer.
            </p>
            <p class="project-description">Satisfied Client.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B2.jpg')"
          title="Cipher"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 02</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B3.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 03</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B4.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 04</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B5.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 05</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B6.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 06</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B7.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 07</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B8.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 08</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B9.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 09</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B10.jpg')"
          title="Cipher"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 10</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B11.jpg')"
          title="Cipher"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 11</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slides" style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B12.jpg')">
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 12</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B13.jpg')"
          title="Cipher"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 13</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CIPHER/B14.jpg')"
          title="Cipher"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">Cipher 14</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBES/001.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBES</p>
            <p class="project-description">
              Description: 2024***
            </p>
            <p class="client">Client: Ghanaian</p>
            <p class="project-description">
              Role: Lead Architectural designer.
            </p>
            <p class="project-description">Satisfied Client.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBES/002.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBES</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBES/003.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBES</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBES/004.jpg')"        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBES</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBES/005.jpg')"        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBES</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBES/006.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBES</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- CUBIOD -->
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBOID/001.jpg')">
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBIOD</p>
            <p class="project-description">
              Description: 2024 2 ***
            </p>
            <p class="client">Client:</p>
            <p class="project-description">
              Role: Lead Architectural designer.
            </p>
            <p class="project-description">Satisfied Client.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBOID/002.jpg')"
          title="CUBIOD 02"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBIOD</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBOID/003.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBIOD</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBOID/004.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBIOD</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBOID/005.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBIOD</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/CUBOID/006.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">CUBIOD</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ECLIPSE-->
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/ECLIPSE/001.jpg')">
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">ECLIPSE</p>
            <p class="project-description">
              Description: 2024***
            </p>
            <p class="client">Client: Ghanaian</p>
            <p class="project-description">
              Role: Lead Architectural designer.
            </p>
            <p class="project-description">Satisfied Client.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/ECLIPSE/002.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">ECLIPSE</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/ECLIPSE/003.jpg')"        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">ECLIPSE</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          class="slides"
          style="--img: url('../projects/ECLIPSE/004.jpg')"
        >
          <div class="content">
            <p class="project-title">ECLIPSE</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <span class="prev" aria-label="Previous Slide"></span>
      <span class="next" aria-label="Next Slide"></span>
    </div>
      </body>
</html>

The CSS
.building--container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding: 20px;
}

.slider .slides {
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-image: var(--img);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 25px 50px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  height: 320px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 240px;
}

.slider .slides:nth-child(1),
.slider .slides:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(0);
  box-shadow: 0 25px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-size: cover;
}


I’ve tried using position: absolute for the .slides elements, but this causes them to overlap other elements in the DOM. I’ve adjusted the layout using flexbox in the .building--container and .slider, but the issue still occurs also attempted using calc() in the max-width property to account for spacing, but it didn’t fix the issue.
Expectations.
I want the gallery to stay within its container without overlapping other elements on the page. It should maintain the layout with proper spacing, without interfering with elements that come after or around it.
Can anyone help me understand what’s causing this overlap and how to fix it?

Your html looks fine here is the css
   .building--container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures slides don't overflow the slider */
  position: relative;
}

.slider .slides {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-image: var(--img);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 25px 50px rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.5);
  height: 320px;
  width: 240px;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* Prevents slides from shrinking */
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out; /* Smooth sliding effect */
  position: relative; /* Allows stacking without unnecessary absolute positioning */
}

.slider .slides:nth-child(1),
.slider .slides:nth-child(2) {
  background-size: cover; /* Ensure proper background sizing */
  z-index: 1; /* Optional: manage stacking order */
}


Your code significantly disrupts the layout and doesn't meet my expectations.
Thanks for answering tho,
